# Exchange 2013: Single user cannot send mail

Tags: hyper-v, exchange-2013

We have Exchange 2013 on a Windows Server 2012 VM (Hyper-V on Windows Server 2012).

Everything has been working for years. But now we suddenly have one user who is no longer able to send any mail. The user can still receive mail normally.

- Everyone else can send mail no problem
- User cannot send mail from any client: Outlook on the LAN, Outlook Web App from the internet, always the same problem. -> Connection error between client and server is not the problem.
- User does not receive an error from the Client or an NDR from the server
- Recently (since the problem appeared) sent messages from user do not show up under Mail Flow -> Delivery Reports
- No error messages from Exchange in Event Log
- Server message queue is empty
- User mailbox has no size limit
- Server still has about 5GB of free disk space

I suspect that disk space may be the problem and will try to double the size of the virtual hard drive. However, that would be strange since the server has at times had less than 4GB of free space and has never experienced any issues before.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding the virtual hard drive by a couple hundred gigs totally solved the problem.

According to [this TechNet Page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee832792(v=exchg.150).aspx) you are supposed to have 20% of the size of your database in free space, I was way below that. So it is to be expected that problems arise.

However, the expected behavior would be that Exchange would first stop accepting incoming mail, issue an error in the event log and finally, when it is really low on space, stop accepting outgoing mail from *all accounts at the same time* and issue another Error.

Why it did none of that and instead shut down one person's ability to send mail *without issuing a single warning or error* eludes me.

Anyway, storage is cheap these days, always have a good amount of free space on your servers. Lesson learned.